# Tensorflow / Keras : Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to implement a Federated training Keras / Tensorflow model for *detecting fake news in text articles*, but I have trouble with the model. When I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 50]
```

And the following warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 400) for input Tensor("embedding_input:0", shape=(None, 400), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```

Intuitively I understand that Embedding Layer Output should be of shape (None, 400, 50) but for some reason it is fed just a 2d input, or that the Layer is expecting a 3d Tensor but is provided just a 2d one. However, I don't know how to fix it, or how to change the input/output shape so that they will match. I've stayed a couple of days on this issue. I'm still new in the field of ML and Neural Networks.  Any suggestions are apreciated, thank you very much in advance.

### The model used:

```
max_words = 2000
max_len = 400
embed_dim = 50
lstm_out = 64
batch_size = 32

def getTextModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(max_words, embed_dim, input_length = max_len, input_shape=preprocessed_sample_dataset.element_spec))
    model.add(LSTM(lstm_out))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, name='out_layer'))
    model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
return model
```

### Model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 400, 50)           100000    
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 64)                29440     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               16640     
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
out_layer (Dense)            (None, 1)                 257       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 146,337
Trainable params: 146,337
Non-trainable params: 0
```

#### Other info:

Preprocessing of the data:

```
def preprocess(dataset):

  def batch_format_fn(element):
    """Flatten a batch `pixels` and return the features as an `OrderedDict`."""
    print(element['features'])
    return collections.OrderedDict(
        x=element['features'],
        y=tf.reshape(element['label'], [-1, 1])
    )
  return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(
      BATCH_SIZE).map(batch_format_fn).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)

preprocessed_sample_dataset = preprocess(sample_dataset)


def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
    return [preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x)) for x in client_ids]

federated_train_data = make_federated_data(train_dataset, train_dataset.client_ids)

print('Number of client datasets: {l}'.format(l=len(federated_train_data)))
print('First dataset: {d}'.format(d=federated_train_data[0]))
```

Dataset format:

```
Number of client datasets: 4
First dataset: <PrefetchDataset shapes: OrderedDict([(x, (None,)), (y, (None, 1))]), types: OrderedDict([(x, tf.string), (y, tf.int64)])>
```

Code where the function is called:

```
def model_fn():

  keras_model = getTextModel() #create_keras_model()
  input_spec_aux = preprocessed_sample_dataset.element_spec
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec= input_spec_aux,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

#Error occurs in iterative_process
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=client_lr),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=server_lr))

print(str(iterative_process.initialize.type_signature))

state = iterative_process.initialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

The dataset format is saying the shape of the input `x` is `(None,)` (ndim/rank, = 1) and dtype `tf.string)`. The `None` comes from the fact that the dataset may yield batches that aren't "full", so in practice the first dimension is in the range `[1, BATCH_SIZE]`. This shape means we have a batch of single scalar strings. This may be where the problem lies, typically in LSTMs we want batches of *sequences* of strings, e.g. a shape like `(None, SEQUENCE_LENGTH)`.

The embedding layer will project the last dimension into the embedding dimension `z`, e.g. take a shape `(x, y)` and produce a shape `(x, y, z)`. So our input after the embedding layer will be `(None, 50)` (or ndim/rank = 2). Recall the LSTM wants sequences, and Keras wants batches, the error message is saying the desired shape was `(None, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, 50)` (ndim/rank = 3).

I would suggest going back to the dataset and determine what the format of `element['features']` is. It seems like it this case it might be a full sentence and need to be tokenized into a sequence of words (e.g. for English split on spaces).

A word of warning though: even after fixing the shapes, I suspect Keras will next complain that the dtype of `tf.string` cannot be used in the Embedding layer. The sequences will first need to be converted to integer ids, likely using something from [`tf.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lookup) or something from `tf_text`.

Some resources that might be helpful:

- [Federated Learning for Text Generation Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation), particular the dataset construction sections.
- [Load text tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text#prepare_the_dataset_for_training)